# haskell min and max from matrix as touple

Tags: haskell

I figured out how to get max and min as a touple from vector:

```
maxminv (x:xs) = foldr (\x (big, small) -> (max x big, min x small)) (x, x) xs
```

For example

```
maxminv [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> (6,1)
```

Now, most probably using this function, I want to get max and min as a touple again, from matrix.

For example

```
maxminm [[1,2,3],[4,5]]
>>> (5,1)
```

Should use foldr/foldl, any idea how to continue with this function?

Answer (score 1):

Flatten the matrix into a list and then apply existing `maxminv`:

```hs
maxminm :: Ord a => [[a]] -> (a, a)
maxminm = maxminv . concat
```

Comment: `join` is also known as `concat` for lists

Comment: A fancier way to implement `maxminv` with `import Control.Arrow`: `maxminv = maximum &&& minimum`.

Comment: @DNNX This traverses the list twice, doesn't it? Could be problematic for a large list.

Comment: An implementation in the same vein that does only one traversal is `foldMap (Just . Min &&& Just . Max) >>> zipA >>> fmap (getMin *** getMax)`, where `zipA = uncurry (liftA2 (,))`, using `Min` and `Max` from `Data.Semigroup`. There’s also the [`foldl`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) package for doing this kind of thing more composably, e.g. `L.fold $ liftA2 (,) L.minimum L.maximum`, or its more general but less documented cousin, [`folds`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/folds).